# Unnumbered appendix chapter but numbered tables/figures R Markdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

In RMarkdown, I would like to have multiple appendix chapters (after references) with a title "Appendix A", "Appendix B", and so on but with numbered figures and tables Figure A.1, Figure A.2. The document class is a book.

So far, I have a main report.rmd script from which I knit to a pdf:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "test test"
geometry: margin=1in
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup{skip=2pt,labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}
---

{r child="01-introduction.rmd", echo=FALSE}
{r child="02-appendix.rmd", echo=FALSE}
```

And the 01-introduction.rmd and 02-appendix.rmd are separate files. In the 02-appendix, the chapter is unnumbered:

```
# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-}

# Appendix A {-}

{r results="asis",eval=TRUE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
# Sample data
data <- data.frame(Name = c("John", "Alice", "Bob"), Age = c(25, 30, 22))
knitr::kable(data, caption = "Sample Table")
```

This does what I want for the chapter header/title, but the  table caption number is Table 1 not Table A.1.